# Wrong logic in do-while statement?

Tags: c, operators, logic, logical-operators

I must tell you that i' ve already searched thi site and other, but i couldn't solve my problem. I'm doing a program that works on some lists. The code copies the values form the second list to the first, with this condition: the current value of list 2 must be lesser than the value in list 1. If this condition is true, the value is copied. But that's not the point.  I made a function called `GetExitValue()`, which at the end of main, gets the input from the user whether to continue or not. And this is the problem. When i call the function in main (inside of a while) , it continues to run the program even if i insert `n` (No). Can you tell me what am i doing wrong?? Thank you very much guys!!

And that's my code semplified.

```
int main(){

    do{
    .
    . 
    .
    .
    printf("\nProgram finished. Do you wish to re-execute the program? \n\nPress y/Y (Yes) to continue. Press n/N (No) to exit. ");

    }
    while(GetExitValue() ==  'y' || 'Y' ); // **Problem here!!**

    return 0;
}


    char GetExitValue(){
        char exit_value;

            scanf(" %c", &exit_value);
            while(exit_value != 'y' && exit_value != 'n' && exit_value != 'Y' && exit_value != 'N'){
                        printf("Value incorrect. insert y or n!!\n");
                        scanf(" %c", &exit_value);
                    }
            return exit_value;
        }
```

Comment: The `||` _logical_ operator works with booleans.  You can't do that.

Comment: `GetExitValue() ==  'y' || GetExitValue() == 'Y'` when `GetExitValue` works well

Comment: This doesn't seem to work as well... :\

Comment: This is because `GetExitValue()` will run twice on the suggested solution in comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This part:

```
while(GetExitValue() ==  'y' || 'Y' ); // **Problem here!!**
```

which you've correctly spotted, is probably **not** doing what you meant. This **always** is "true" because 'Y' (which is not 0 in [ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/)) is always "true".

You literally have this in your code: `while (condition || 1)` which can be useful, but not in this case.

You probably mean this:

```
.
.
// run GetExitValue() only once...
char gev = GetExitValue();
}
while(gev ==  'y' || gev == 'Y' );
```

And I'll just point out that you can do something like:

```
.
.
}
while(GetExitValue()); // no need to store value!
```

if only you'd change `GetExitValue()` to return 0 when user does not want it to run again:

```
char GetExitValue(){
    char exit_value;

        scanf(" %c", &exit_value);
        while(exit_value != 'y' && exit_value != 'n' && exit_value != 'Y' && exit_value != 'N'){
                    printf("Value incorrect. insert y or n!!\n");
                    scanf(" %c", &exit_value);
                }

        return exit_value == 'Y' || exit_value == 'y'; //evaluates to 1 if true
    }
```

It will probably be cleaner, and you can change it's name to `shouldRunAgain()` which to my personal taste is more informative :)

Comment: Thank you very much!! this works flawlessy.. Btw is there another way to do this without that more char?? i mean it's not possible to do that with the function called into the while??  And by the way i can't  upvote your answer because i haven't got enough reputation. But Thank you anyway. This was very helpful!!

Comment: I've added something. please test it in your code and report back :) you can accept the answer if you find it useful.

Comment: Thanl you again you're amazing!! :D

Comment: make sure to test it and report back. I'll run it in a bit.

Comment: Ok i got it compiled and running. It works very well!!

Answer (score 0):

The while expression is evaluated as:

```
while( ( GetExitValue() ==  'y' ) || 'Y' );
```

So the expression is always true because *anything or true == true*.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here-

`while(GetExitValue() ==  'y' || 'Y' );`

The 'Y' part will always be true, because in C, anything that isn't a zero(false) is true.
the ASCII value of 'Y' isn't zero, therefore, the while condition will always return true.

What you should do is this-

```
`char x=GetExitValue();
 while(x ==  'y' || x=='Y' );`
```